# Open Eclipse View in RCP headless mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, rcp

I have headless (CLI) RCP app, normally handling command line options, but i'd occasionally need to show parts of the a gui anyway.
Is there a way to open a view part standalone(detached is fine) when PlatformUI/Workbench is not running?

WorkbenchPage.showView(the one I'd normally use to open the view) normally throws "workbench is not running" exception, which is expected of course in headless mode.

Is there some reasonable hack to do this? I tried running the RCP workbench with the event loop - the problem is that it's blocking execution and it seems too heavyweight.

I know I can create new Shell embedding the widget of the view, for it but then I'd miss the toolbars/menus that come with the proper view.

Answer (score 2):

All the UI code is completely dependent on the workbench running. The workbench must be started with `PlatformUI.createandRunWorkbench`. So it is not possible to show a UI without doing this.

The simple SWT only Shell seems the easiest way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I use plain Shell, I'd like to reuse as much of the view as possible, e.g Menus,Toolbars(ActionBars). I guess this means some refactoring on the view code (which I own and it's probably a good thing anyway).. The goal is to make it look like in the embedded state. Any ideas on how best to do this?

Comment: Having said SWT only I think JFace will be OK as well. Sorry never looked at doing anything like this.

Comment: Hmm, good point about JFace - not sure how exactly to use it for the above purpose, but ApplicationWindow looks interesting. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the concept of RCP, and work with SWT/JFace components only.

Build some factory methods that simulate `PlatformUI.createandRunWorkbench`. Instead, they will create `Shell`s and run the event loops themselves.

To me, this seems like a bit of an overkill if the app is going to be large. It it's not THAT enterprise-ish, then I guess you could do without the workbench framework. Be careful for dangling resources, though.

Comment: Yep, that's the conclusion I'm coming to.. I was just hoping to minimise extra work by reusing the view as-is with as little plumbing or reinventing the wheel. In the meantime got it up and running with JFace ApplicationWindow, also with the view menu - but had to refactor the view code for this.. (If there were toolbars/etc I'd have to deal with those separately, wasting a bit more time). If I could plug in the ActionBars stuff it would be a good compromise.